# Import and add index to mongodb on a Dokku install

Tags: node.js, mongodb, dokku

I have a recently deployed app on an Ubuntu server using Dokku.  This is a Node.js app with a Mongodb database.

For the site to work properly I need to to load geojson file in the database.  On my development machine this was done from the ubuntu command line using the mongoimport command.  I can't figure out how to do this in Dokku.

I also need to add a geospatial index.  This was done from the mongo console on my development machine.  I also cant figure out how to do that on the Dokku install.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mongodump` will export all the data + indexes from an existing database.
https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongodump/

Then `mongorestore` will restore a mongodump with indexes to an existing database.
https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongorestore/

> mongorestore recreates indexes recorded by mongodump.

You can do both commands from you dev machine to the Dokku database.

Comment: I can't figure out how to access the mongo database directly.  

From my local machine used mongodump to produce a dump file.I tried using the dokku mongo tool but it doesn't like my bson file.


Here are the commands that I tried:
`$ dokku mongo:import mongo_claims < docs4.bson
tar: This does not look like a tar archive
tar: Skipping to next header
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors`

Comment: Also I tried to tar the bson file but it still didn't work.

`$ dokku mongo:import mongo_claims < docs4.tar
2016-03-05T02:46:41.391+0000 using default 'dump' directory
2016-03-05T02:46:41.392+0000 Failed: can't create ActualPath object from path dump: stat dump: no such file or directory`

Comment: Move your bson to a folder named dump and tar this folder

Answer (score 4):

Thanks a lot @Jonathan.  You helped me solve this problem.  Here is what I did.

I used `mongodump` on my local machine to create a backup file of the database.  It defaulted to a .bson file.

I uploaded that file to my remote server.  On the remote server I put the bson file inside a folder called "dump".  Then tarred that folder.  I initially used the -z flag out of habit but mongo/dokku didn't like the gzip. So I used tar with no compression like so:

```
tar -cvf dump.tar dump
```

next I ran the dokku mongo import command:

```
$dokku mongo:import mongo_claims < dump.tar
2016-03-05T18:04:17.255+0000    building a list of collections to restore from /tmp/tmp.6S378QKhJR/dump dir
2016-03-05T18:04:17.270+0000    restoring mongo_claims.docs4 from /tmp/tmp.6S378QKhJR/dump/docs4.bson
2016-03-05T18:04:20.729+0000    [############............]  mongo_claims.docs4  22.3 MB/44.2 MB  (50.3%)
2016-03-05T18:04:22.821+0000    [########################]  mongo_claims.docs4  44.2 MB/44.2 MB  (100.0%)
2016-03-05T18:04:22.822+0000    no indexes to restore
2016-03-05T18:04:22.897+0000    finished restoring mongo_claims.docs4 (41512 documents)
2016-03-05T18:04:22.897+0000    done
```

That did the trick.  My site immediately had all the data.

Answer (score 0):

Importing works well, but since you mentionned mongo console, it's nice to know that you can also connect to your Mongo instance if you use https://github.com/dokku/dokku-mongo's `mongo:list` and `mongo:connect`...

E.g.:

```
root@somewhere:~# dokku mongo:list
NAME      VERSION      STATUS   EXPOSED PORTS   LINKS
mydb      mongo:3.2.1  running  1->2->3->4->5   mydb

root@somewhere:~# dokku mongo:connect mydb
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.1
connecting to: mydb
> db
mydb

  Mongo shell!

> exit
bye
```

Answer (score 0):

For dokku v0.5.0+ and dokku-mongo v1.7.0+

Use `mongodump` to export your data into an archive:

```
mongodump --db mydb --gzip --archive=mydb.archive
```

Use `dokku:import` to import your data from an archive

```
dokku mongo:import mydb < mydb.archive
```